# Combine animation actions into one?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature, unity

I need the arms head and legs of my zombie model to vary in colors, so I have to keep them separate, but I need an armature, so I need more than one armature, meaning I'll have multiple animation strips. How do i Combine these or whats the easiest solution?

Unity has problems importing materials and it doesn't look good when i bend the arms if its all one armature.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by combine?

Comment: I literally mean make one action strip that contains two actions

Comment: So that a single animation can be used in a game and use all actions I want it to

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're going for, but you could probably manipulate the keyframes and make them overlap by moving them in the dope sheet.
I hope that helps! (But I'm kind of afraid it won't.)

Comment: No I need it all in one action

Comment: If you need them to vary in colour, why can't you simply assign different materials to different faces?

Comment: Dude come on... Read the question. I'm talking about animation here. In unity colors get mixed up when sharing one mesh

Comment: You can use 1 armature to deform multiple objects. Why do you need 1 armature for every zombie part?

Comment: Because my model isn't being properly bent by the arms and legs when with one armature

Comment: I did read the question. And nowhere does it say anything about Unity. It only states that you need separate objects to have separate colours.

Comment: But my question was about animation, regardless.

Comment: Does anyone know, though, how to do what I asked in the question?

Comment: Indeed it was. And I simply wanted to know *why* you needed separate objects to be able to have different colours during animation. And if Unity can't handle different colours on one mesh, perhaps you should file a bug report.

Comment: It does handle them, just the colors get mixed up.

Comment: but the other reason i need them separated is because it doesn't look right when one armature is attached to the whole thing

Comment: Would you like to edit your question to avoid future misunderstandings? You don't *have* to, but it may help clear some stuff up. As it is, I'm voting a close on this question because it's not *quite* clear what your exact question is.

Comment: Then I really have no idea what you're trying to do. Sorry.